# Find the worst case running time T(n) and its complexity in O-notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Here is the problem that I'm working with:

```
Algorithm Income ()

   int i=0;
   while i<n
   .....
```

What I think: I think that **t(n)= n** and **O(n)**.
Why  I think that:  I think that because, when I initialize `i=0` , that's 1 operation  cost , and when I check the while condition the operation is n-1.
So if I add all the operations together I get n.

---

If anyone could please help me understand how to solve this question or help modify my understanding , then I would appreciate it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One correction I will like to make to your understanding is that the 2 operations:
`int i=0;` and `while i<n` are independent so there cost will be added.

Let's call cost of `i=0` as **c1** and as you correctly mentioned **c1=1**

Let's call cost of `while i<n` as **c2**.
Now c2 **will not be n-1**. It will be **n**. Reason is that you are starting from 0 and going all the way till **n-1**. Cost would have been **n-1** if you would have gone from 1 to n-1.

So total cost = **c1+c2** = n+1.

Now for larger n, we can ignore the constant cost 1, therefore we say it's O(n)